# RESTAssured - use .pfx certificate for https call

Tags: https, rest-assured

I am trying to make a HTTPs call using RESTAssured. I am using a .pfx certficate. But the call is ending in a handshake failure. Below is the code I am using.

```
    FileInputStream instream1=null;
    FileInputStream instream2=null;
    KeyStore trustStore=null;
    KeyStore keyStore=null;


    instream1 = new FileInputStream(new File(keystore)); 
    keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12"); 
    keyStore.load(instream1, keystorepwd.toCharArray()); 

    instream2 = new FileInputStream (new File(truststore)); 
    trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks"); 
    trustStore.load(instream2, truststorepwd.toCharArray()); 

    X509HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;
    org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory lSchemeSocketFactory=null;
    lSchemeSocketFactory = new org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory(keyStore, keystorepwd);
    lSchemeSocketFactory.setHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
    RestAssured.config = RestAssured.config().sslConfig(new SSLConfig().with().sslSocketFactory(lSchemeSocketFactory).and().allowAllHostnames());

    response = RestAssured.given()
            .relaxedHTTPSValidation()
            .contentType("application/json")
            .header("Accept-Encoding","gzip,deflate")
            .body(\\body)
  .post()
    .then().log().all()
    .assertThat().statusCode(201)
    .assertThat().extract().response();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue with a small modification.

```
FileInputStream instream1=null;
KeyStore keyStore=null;


instream1 = new FileInputStream(new File(keystore)); 
keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12"); 
keyStore.load(instream1, keystorepwd.toCharArray()); 

X509HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;
org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory lSchemeSocketFactory=null;
lSchemeSocketFactory = new org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory(keyStore, keystorepwd);
lSchemeSocketFactory.setHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
RestAssured.config = RestAssured.config().sslConfig(new SSLConfig().with().sslSocketFactory(lSchemeSocketFactory).and().allowAllHostnames());

response = RestAssured.given()
        .relaxedHTTPSValidation()
        .contentType("application/json")
        .header("Accept-Encoding","gzip,deflate")
        .body(\\body)
.post()
.then().log().all()
.assertThat().statusCode(201)
.assertThat().extract().response();
```

Comment: The above didn't work for me, however, removing the `.relaxedHTTPSValidation()` line made it work. From digging in to the Rest Assured code, it seems that the `relaxedHTTPSValidation()` method basically turns off all SSL, and removes the keystore set up in the preceding lines.