# rest-assured with pfx file always returns 401

Tags: authorization, rest-assured, pfx

From this source: [RESTAssured - use .pfx certificate for https call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235588/restassured-use-pfx-certificate-for-https-call)
I created below.

```java
    @Test
    void testPfxKey() {
        // Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235588/restassured-use-pfx-certificate-for-https-call

        FileInputStream instream1=null;
        KeyStore keyStore=null;
        org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory lSchemeSocketFactory=null;
        try {
            instream1 = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Path/To/pfxfile.pfx"));
            keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            keyStore.load(instream1, "pfxfilepwd".toCharArray());
            X509HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;
            lSchemeSocketFactory = new org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory(keyStore, "pfxfilepwd");
            lSchemeSocketFactory.setHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        RestAssured.config = RestAssured.config().sslConfig(new SSLConfig().with().sslSocketFactory(lSchemeSocketFactory).and().allowAllHostnames().relaxedHTTPSValidation());
        RestAssured.given().
                contentType("application/json").
                headers(
                        "Subscription-Key", "key-value",
                        "Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate"
                );
        Response response = RestAssured.get("https://endpoint.net/resource/path");
        System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
    }
```

response.getStatusCode() always returns 401. I am expecting a 200. I have checked keyfile path, password and also the enpoint. All seem to be OK. When I run use ReadyAPI then I get a response. Please advice how to resolve this issue. Thanks you all!

Comment: Did you try remove `.relaxedHTTPSValidation()` b/c it will turn off HTTPS setting and discard your certificate as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue! I need to send headers with each request. Also .relaxedHTTPSValidation() should NOT be used in this case. We are in fact providing certificates that should be authenticated! Below code works:

```
@Test
void testPfxKey() {
    FileInputStream instream1 = null;
    KeyStore keyStore = null;
    org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory lSchemeSocketFactory = null;
    try {
        instream1 = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Path/To/pfxfile.pfx"));
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        keyStore.load(instream1, "pfxfilepwd".toCharArray());
        X509HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;
        lSchemeSocketFactory = new org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory(keyStore, "pfxfilepwd");
        lSchemeSocketFactory.setHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    RestAssured.config = RestAssured.config().sslConfig(new SSLConfig().with().sslSocketFactory(lSchemeSocketFactory).and().allowAllHostnames());
        System.out.println(
    RestAssured.given().
            contentType("application/json").
            headers(
                    "Subscription-Key", "key-value",
                    "Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate"
            )
            .get("https://endpoint.net/resource/path")
            .getStatusCode()
            );
}
```